# Get documents and folders in SharePoint 2010 list's ROOT folder with REST

Tags: 2010, list, rest, soap

There is a [question about getting files/folders in some SharePoint folder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104757/how-to-list-documents-in-a-sharepoint-2010-folder-with-rest/104761#104761). There is advice to filter list items by parent folder path. But how can I list files/folders in the List itself?
With **REST** I can only get list **short name** (e.g. `'AppPackages'`). It allows me getting list content with REST service `'_vti_bin/ListData.svc/AppPackages'`, but I cannot get neither **readable name/title** (e.g. `'App Packages'`) for showing it nor **root folder path** (e.g. `'/Lists/AppPackages'`) for further filtering immediate files/folders.
I tried **SOAP** and I could get both **title** and **root folder** for list but cannot get **short list name** to use it further in REST calls. There is also no stable way to find correspondence between SOAP-obtained (title, root folder) pair and REST-obtained short name

Ideas and comments are very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve items from a specific folder in Library and print File/Folder `Name` and `Url` properties:

```
function getListItemsInFolder(webUrl,listName,folderPath) 
{
    var folderUrl = webUrl + '/' + listName + '/' + folderPath;
    return $.ajax({       
       url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/" + listName + "?$filter=Path eq '" + folderUrl + "'",   
       type: "GET",   
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: { 
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }
    });
}


getListItemsInFolder(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl,'Documents','Orders')
.done(function(data)
{
    var items = data.d.results;
    for(var i =0; i < items.length;i++) {
      console.log(items[i].Name);  
      console.log(items[i].Path + '/' + items[i].Name);       
    }
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: Well, the question was how to list items from the list itself when I do not know its folder path. In your example, I need to list items from `'Documents'` list. Note that `'Documents' != '/Shared Documents'` though they correspond each other. So `var folderUrl = webUrl + '/' + listName + '/' + folderPath;` is not always correct.

I have added "ROOT" to the question caption for clarity.