# How do I access the docs in a Sharepoint folder via REST API?

Tags: 2010, rest

I am a total beginner with Sharepoint, actually I do not know much about the internal structures used by Sharepoint and what exactly can and can not be accessed via REST Apis

Here is what I am trying to do: we have a site where docs relevant to our projects are stored. I need to go to this site and extract a list of files that are is a specific folder

If I use https://servername/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/SharedDocuments/ I get a webpage saying that

*You are viewing a feed that contains frequently updated content. When you subscribe to a feed, it is added to the Common Feed List. Updated information from the feed is automatically downloaded to your computer and can be viewed in Internet Explorer and other programs. Learn more about feeds.*

I know that when I use my browser to access this folder I need to use the following path to get to my files

SiteName->Shared Documents->Installation Data -> Latest Files

There is a couple of views to call them so that seem to have been defined by the site admin and using those I can sort documents by their various attributes

Based on the above can anybody please help me to find out what is the complete REST API request that I have to use to get a list of files in the Installation Data subfolder ?

Thanks a lot
C

PS: I am using Python to process this data but for now I would be happy with at least a http REST request like the one that takes me to the Shared Documents foldre

Comment: I removed my answer as it was for 2013 and Office 365. The answer was moved to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148760/how-do-i-list-files-in-a-doclib-folder-via-rest-api/

Comment: There is an answer to a very similar question for 2010 but it is not working for me http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104757/how-to-list-documents-in-a-sharepoint-2010-folder-with-rest  Apparently the docs that I have are in a Document Library , more exactly in the Shared Documents library.Within this library I have a couple of folders which I should see when I use https://servername/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/SharedDocuments  BUT I am not getting anything listed. I see that Sharepoint 2013 has the "site" interjected in the link (http://zoom.it/zdjx#full).Not sure if 2010 needs that too

Comment: Can this be a permission to use REST API issue ? All the collections are listed properly when I use https://servername/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ but when I add a collection name at the end of the above URL I get an empty reply