# How do I list files in a DocLib folder via REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

How do I use the SharePoint REST API to list the contents of a folder in a document library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a little bit of setup to get the correct folder. First, use the REST API to get the list of items inside of the document library.

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Shared Documents')/files
```

Based on the result, search for the entry with the folder name in the `<name>` element that is directly under the `<entity>` element (the other name elements are for user info and such). The ID of the record will take you to the detailed description of that item.

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists(guid'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')/files('VeIoeslIeovSZcve_fdinve-dfklasjfkfjeiaLCVdvEvneiseljvajjPe5lxkvz')
```

Append `/childen` to the end of the query to get the list of files and folders in under the selected folder.